# The returned value of resultset to get the object is null

Tags: mysql, jdbc

this is my code.

```
Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select age from filesearch");
System.out.println(rs.next());//The return value is: null
if(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getObject("age"));
}
```

This is the variable in my database tables:

Listing:manager,age

data type:varchar,int

length:100,100

default:D:\Java\manager,10

Comment: The return value of `ResultSet.next()` is `boolean`. It is ***impossible*** for that to be null. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) for `ResultSet#next()`, this method returns a boolean, so you should never be seeing null from your print statement.  That being said, you are not using the JDBC API correctly, and you should be using a pattern similar to this:

```
Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select age from filesearch");
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getObject("age"));
}
```